# How to add dummy variables to data with specific characteristic

Tags: r, panel-data

My question is probably quite basic but I've been struggling with it so I'd be really grateful if someone could offer a solution.

I have data in the following format:

| ORG_NAME | var_1_12 | var_1_13 | var_1_14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 11 | 5 |
| B | 13 | 13 | 11 |
| C | 6 | 7 | NA |
| D | NA | NA | 5 |

I have data on organizations over 5 years, but over that time, some organizations have merged and others have disappeared. I'm planning on conducting a fixed-effects regression, so I need to add a dummy variable which is "0" when organizations have remained the same (in this case row A and row B), and "1" in the year before the merge, and after the merge. In this case, I know that orgs C and D merged, so I would like for the data to look like this:

| ORG_NAME | var_1_12 | dum_12 | var_1_13 | dum_13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| B | 13 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| C | 6 | 1 | NA | 1 |
| D | NA | 1 | 5 | 1 |

How would I code this?

Comment: What indication is there in your first table that `C` and `D` either *about about to merge* or *have already merged*? The names `var_1_12` and `var_1_13` don't seem immediately useful.

Comment: Most of the organizations are named geographically, so I know that in 90% of cases, the organizations that are close alphabetically (and that share similar names) have merged. Var_1_12 indicates the year and the value in that year (in this case I'm measuring financial returns). Does that answer your question?

Comment: No. There are three properties associated with `C`: 6, 7, and NA. There are three properties associated with `D`: Na, NA, and 5. Using just those data, how do you know that `C` have already or are about to merge? Is it that `C`'s NA is in the column where `D` has data, and vice versa?

Comment: And why do the `var_1_14` values pverwrote `var_1_13`? What happens to the previous values in `var_1_13`?

Comment: Yes! I know that C and D are going to merge because C has data where D doesn't and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach (as is any, according to your description) is absolutely dependent on the companies being in consecutive rows.

```r
mtx <- apply(is.na(dat[,-1]), MARGIN = 2,
             function(vec) zoo::rollapply(vec, 2, function(z) xor(z[1], z[2]), fill = FALSE))
mtx
#      var_1_12 var_1_13 var_1_14
# [1,]    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
# [2,]    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
# [3,]     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
# [4,]    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE

out <- rowSums(mtx) == ncol(mtx)
out
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
out | c(FALSE, out[-length(out)])
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

### and your 0/1 numbers, if logical isn't right for you
+(out | c(FALSE, out[-length(out)]))
# [1] 0 0 1 1
```

Brief walk-through:

- `is.na(dat[,-1])` returns a matrix of whether the values (except the first column) are `NA`; because it's a matrix, we use `apply` to call a function on each column (using `MARGIN=2`);
- `zoo::rollapply` is a function that does rolling calculations on a portion ("window") of the vector at a time, in this case 2-wide. For example, if we have `1:5`, then it first looks at `c(1,2)`, then `c(2,3)`, then `c(3,4)`, etc.
- `xor` is an eXclusive OR, meaning it will be true when one of its arguments are true and the other is false;
- `mtx` is a matrix indicating that a cell and the one below it met the conditions (one is `NA`, the other is not). We then check to see which of these rows are all true, forming `out`.
- since we need a `1` in both rows, we vector-AND `&` out with itself, shifted, to produce your intended output

Comment: Thank you so much, and specifically for breaking down the solution- I want to learn and get better not just copy and paste a solution. I'll try this now!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to code with "1" rows with at least one NA. if it's so, you just need one dummy var for all the years, right? Somthing like this

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(org=as.factor(LETTERS[1:5]),y1=sample(c(1:4,NA),5),y2=sample(c(3:6,NA),5),y3=sample(c(2:5,NA),5))
df$dummy <- as.numeric(apply(df, 1, function(x)any(is.na(x))))
```

which give you

```
org y1 y2 y3 dummy
1   A  3  5  3     0
2   B NA  4  5     1
3   C  4  3  2     0
4   D  1  6 NA     1
5   E  2 NA  4     1
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for offering a solution, I'd like to preserve as much data as possible, which is why I wanted to just assign 1 in the years before and after NA (so I can hopefully interpret the non-merged years). Does that make sense? If it's not possible I will definitely do what you suggest though so thank you!